# How to see the fact that $\{(a,ab) | a,b ∈ \Bbb C^2\}$ is not an affine variety in $\Bbb C^2$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

I agree that it is not an variety because we cannot write it as the variety defined by the polynomial $y-bx$, since here the $b$ is not fixed. I think there is a key point is that we get two parameters instead of only a single parameter, so we cannot fix a set of polynomial such that the set $\{(a,ab) | a,b ∈ \Bbb C^2\}$ is exactly its solution set. But I wonder how I can give a **formal proof** that it cannot be zero locus for any set of polynomials(perhaps by contradiction, I think). May I please ask for a proof? Any references are also appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: Now I am also wondering if I can prove it without using the fact that this set is not closed. If such a method exists, could someone let me know? Thanks.

Comment: It might help to see what the set actually is. It is all points with non-zero first coordinate, along with the origin.

Comment: The argument you give isn't even an informal proof. Instead, note that the set isn't even closed in $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Comment: @anomaly I did notice that it is not a closed set... But I am not allowed to use this fact to imply that this is not a variety.

Comment: @PropositionX: Why not?

Comment: @anomaly Because it is not taught to us yet...

Comment: Then prove it. It's only one line.

Comment: @anomaly Okay I would do so, it is easy enough.